# How can I print the high-score from the snake game that I made?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I'm trying to implement a high-score feature in my snake game. The idea behind it is that I would put all the `food_collision_score`, which is the score I would increment each time my snake comes in contact with a 'food' item, in an array right after it is `reset()`.

I have implemented the code down below, and everything works fine except for the fact that there is no indication of 'high score' being printed anywhere on the screen, as well as no sign of it being updated.

Here is my code:

```
import turtle
import random

w = 500
h = 500
food_size = 10
delay = 100

offsets = {
    "up": (0, 20),
    "down": (0, -20),
    "left": (-20, 0),
    "right": (20, 0)
}

total_scores = []

def reset():
    global snake, snake_dir, food_position, pen, food_collision_count, total_scores
    snake = [[-180, 30], [-180, 50], [-180, 70], [-180, 90], [-180, 110]]
    snake_dir = "up"
    food_collision_count = 0
    food_position = get_random_food_position()
    food.goto(food_position)
    total_scores.append(food_collision_count)
    move_snake()

def move_snake():
    global snake_dir, pen, food_position, food_collision_count, total_scores

    new_head = snake[-1].copy()
    new_head[0] += offsets[snake_dir][0]
    new_head[1] += offsets[snake_dir][1]

    for i in range(2):
        if new_head[i] > w / 2:
            new_head[i] -= w
        elif new_head[i] < -w / 2:
            new_head[i] += w

    if new_head in snake[:-1]:
        reset()
        return

    snake.append(new_head)

    x = 0

    if get_distance(new_head, food_position) < 20:
        food_collision_count = food_collision_count + 1
        update_food_collision_count()
        
        food_position = get_random_food_position()
        food.goto(food_position)
        x += food_collision_count
    else:
        snake.pop(0)

    update_snake_on_screen()

    turtle.ontimer(move_snake, delay)

def update_snake_on_screen():
    pen.clearstamps()
    for segment in snake:
        pen.goto(segment[0], segment[1])
        pen.stamp()
    screen.update()

def update_food_collision_count():
    pen_count.clear()
    pen_count.goto(0, h / 2 - 20)
    pen_count.write(f"Food Collision Count: {food_collision_count}", align="center", font=("Arial", 12, "normal"))
    screen.update()

def print_high_score():
    max_score = max(total_scores, default=0)
    pen_count.clear()
    pen_count.goto(10, h / 2 - 20)
    pen_count.write(f"Max Collision Count: {max_score}", align="center", font=("Arial", 12, "normal"))
    screen.update()

def get_random_food_position():
    x = random.randint(-w / 2 + food_size, w / 2 - food_size)
    y = random.randint(-h / 2 + food_size, h / 2 - food_size)
    return (x, y)

def get_distance(pos1, pos2):
    x1, y1 = pos1
    x2, y2 = pos2
    distance = ((y2 - y1) ** 2 + (x2 - x1) ** 2) ** 0.5
    return distance

def update_direction(new_direction):
    global snake_dir, current_direction
    if snake_dir != opposite_direction(current_direction):
        snake_dir = new_direction

def change_direction(direction):
    global snake_dir, current_direction

    current_direction = snake_dir

    switch = {
        "up": lambda: update_direction("up"),
        "right": lambda: update_direction("right"),
        "down": lambda: update_direction("down"),
        "left": lambda: update_direction("left"),
    }

    switch.get(direction, lambda: None)()

def opposite_direction(current_direction):
    opposites = {"up": "down", "down": "up", "left": "right", "right": "left"}
    return opposites.get(current_direction, current_direction)

def handle_direction_key(direction):
    switch = {
        "Up": "up",
        "Right": "right",
        "Down": "down",
        "Left": "left",
    }

    change_direction(switch.get(direction, ""))

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(w, h)
screen.title("Snake")
screen.bgcolor("blue")
screen.tracer(0)

pen = turtle.Turtle("square")
pen.penup()

pen_count = turtle.Turtle()
pen_count.hideturtle()
pen_count.penup()

food = turtle.Turtle()
food.shape("square")
food.color("yellow")
food.shapesize(food_size / 20)
food.penup()

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(lambda: handle_direction_key("Up"), "Up")
screen.onkey(lambda: handle_direction_key("Right"), "Right")
screen.onkey(lambda: handle_direction_key("Down"), "Down")
screen.onkey(lambda: handle_direction_key("Left"), "Left")

reset()

turtle.done()
```

P.S. to save time, the code bits that you should focus on are `reset()`, `move_snake()`, `print_high_score()`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You don't seem to be calling the `print_high_score` function anywhere?